# Force Scons to flush, or wait until actions completed, runtime linker fails to load files

Tags: linux, glibc, scons

I'm having an issue that it doesn't appear that the file operations in scons are completely finished by the time the action in `AddPostAction` is called.

For example I have this code:

```
def BuildStdLibrary(target, source, env):
    #time.sleep(1)
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(str(target[0])))
    os.system( path + '/build_std_library.sh' )

env.AddPostAction( exe, BuildStdLibrary )
```

`exe` comes from an `Install` command, and also has a `env.Depends( exe, [ sbuild, slib ] )`

The problem I'm having is that the shared library loader is failing. I genereated a core dump and the stack trace is inside the `_dl_*` functions. If I enable the `sleep` in my code the problem goes away. It seems like something wasn't quite ready at the time `BuildStdLibrary` was called. (I'm not entirely clear on precisely what the root cause is.)

I'd like to know how to fix this problem (preferably without a sleep). I'm trying to run a command after all the files have been installed, and commands run. But it has to be properly after they have completed, nothing may be left open, or waiting for async completion it appears.

Is there a way to do this in scons, or should I structure my scons code differently?

---

*Update*: I can confirm that a file sync does fix the issue:

```
    import ctypes
    libc = ctypes.CDLL("libc.so.6")
    libc.sync()
```

Alas, `os.sync` isn't available in Python2 (in which scons runs I believe). I need to do an import like above, which isn't cross-platform.

---

Scons version "v2.4.1.rel_2.4.1" 
Linux 4.4.0-98 (Ubuntu 16.04)
Python 2.7.12

Comment: You'll need a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to have any hope of a useful answer.

Comment: Can you show what an example command line is for the build_std_library.sh given a target?  Does it need to be run with abspath's dir? Or would ${TARGET.dir} be sufficient?  IN which case you could drop the string and do.  env.AddPostAction( exe, "${TARGET.dir}/build_std_library.sh" ).  Which platform, which version or python, which version of SCons?

Comment: It doesn't need absolute path, so I can simplify that. The directory itself isnt' that relevant to the issue. Adding versions to question.

Comment: @EmployedRussian A MCVE is not possible. I've tracked the issue to file caching though, and am hoping somebody has had a similar problem with syncing the FS.

Comment: There have been similar issues reported, but only with parallel builds on windows.

Comment: @bdbaddog I do have parallel building enable and do see multiple cores working (all 8 of them when doing the C++ compilation parts).

Comment: Have you tried building a command string instead of directly calling os.system?

Comment: I was using a command string before building this function (I had the command string as the argument to PostAction). I just created the function to test adding a delay.